# ¿Cómo dividir los datos de una columna de un dataset en dos columnas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataset

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Pandas y Matplotlib y estoy realizando un análisis a partir de unos datos de precipitación y temperatura promedio mensuales de una ciudad. Estos datos originalmente los tengo de manera horizontal, es decir, que tengo un Dataset de 1 fila x 24 columnas. Luego, usando el comando `df.T` cambié las columnas por filas, pero quiero hacer dos nuevas columnas, una llamada "Precipitación" que contenga los valores desde "enepreci30a" hasta "dicpreci30a" y otra llamada "Temperatura" que contenga los valores desde "enetemp30a" hasta "dictemp30a",es decir, que me quede lo siguiente:

```
Mes Precipitación (mm) Temperatura (°C)
ene 63.2                22.4
feb 81.4                22.7
mar 129.1               22.7
abr 170.7               22.4
may 213.5               22.6
jun 149.4               22.9
jul 133.1               23.1
ago 139.7               23.1
sep 181.8               22.4
oct 226.7               21.8         
nov 158.9               21.8  
dic 104.8               21.9
```

Esto es lo que he realizado hasta ahora:

```
precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_2=precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín.drop(['Código','Departamento','Municipio','Latitud','Coordenada Latitud','Longitud','Coordenada Longitud','Altitud (msnm)'],axis=1)
precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_2.info()
print(precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_2)
precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_2.T

 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 382 to 382
Data columns (total 24 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   enepreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 1   febpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 2   marpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 3   abrpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 4   maypreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 5   junpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 6   julpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 7   agopreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 8   seppreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 9   octpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 10  novpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 11  dicpreci30a  1 non-null      float64
 12  enetemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 13  febtemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 14  martemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 15  abrtemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 16  maytemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 17  juntemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 18  jultemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 19  agotemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 20  septemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 21  octtemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 22  novtemp30a   1 non-null      float64
 23  dictemp30a   1 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(24)
memory usage: 280.0 bytes
     enepreci30a  febpreci30a  marpreci30a  abrpreci30a  maypreci30a  \
382         63.2         81.4        129.1        170.7        213.5   

     junpreci30a  julpreci30a  agopreci30a  seppreci30a  octpreci30a  ...  \
382        149.4        133.1        139.7        181.8        226.7  ...   

     martemp30a  abrtemp30a  maytemp30a  juntemp30a  jultemp30a  agotemp30a  \
382        22.7        22.4        22.6        22.9        23.1        23.1   

     septemp30a  octtemp30a  novtemp30a  dictemp30a  
382        22.4        21.8        21.8        21.9  

[1 rows x 24 columns]      

    382
enepreci30a 63.2
febpreci30a 81.4
marpreci30a 129.1
abrpreci30a 170.7
maypreci30a 213.5
junpreci30a 149.4
julpreci30a 133.1
agopreci30a 139.7
seppreci30a 181.8
octpreci30a 226.7
novpreci30a 158.9
dicpreci30a 104.8
enetemp30a  22.4
febtemp30a  22.7
martemp30a  22.7
abrtemp30a  22.4
maytemp30a  22.6
juntemp30a  22.9
jultemp30a  23.1
agotemp30a  23.1
septemp30a  22.4
octtemp30a  21.8
novtemp30a  21.8
dictemp30a  21.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se me ocurre que la manera mas sencilla de hacerlo es asi:

```
df2 = df[:12]
df3 = df[12:]
```

De esta manera estas dividiendo tu DataFrame original en dos DataFrame de 12 filas cada uno, de hecho esta pregunta fue respondida en el siguiente post [Split pandas dataframe in two if it has more than 10 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290757/split-pandas-dataframe-in-two-if-it-has-more-than-10-rows)